# There is no row at position 0....what should i do..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        {
            if (TexBo_num.Text == "" && TexBo_num.Text != "contact_no")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Either contact_number is empty or Wrong');", true);
            }else

            {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SYSTEM2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amresh;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter value = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM detail WHERE contact_no ="+TexBo_num.Text, con);
            DataSet val = new DataSet();
            value.Fill(val);

            if ((val.Tables[0].Rows[0]["contact_no"]).ToString() == TexBo_num.Text)
            {

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,address from detail where contact_no =" + TexBo_num.Text, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                string nam = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                string add = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
                TxtBox_name.Text = nam;
                TexBo_add.Text = add;
            }else

            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('value not found');", true);
            }


                con.Close();
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the textbox with the `contact_no` contains a value not present in the `detail` table then you don't have any rows returned by the SqlDataAdapter fill method. But you could check this situation with

```
if (val.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    TxtBox_name.Text = val.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
    TexBo_add.Text  = val.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
}
```

Note that is not needed to query again the database to retrieve the name and address from the table detail. You have already that info in the `val` Dataset.

Said that, remember to always avoid string concatenations to form a sql command text, but use always a parameterized query. This will remove any possibility of an Sql Injection security problem.

To summarize your code could be rewritten as

```
// Ask to return just the data you need, not the whole rows
string commandText = "select name,address from detail where contact_no = @num");
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
{
     con.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", Convert.ToInt32(TexBo_num.Text));
     using(SqlDataAdapter value = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
     {
         DataSet val = new DataSet();
         value.Fill(val);
         if (val.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             TxtBox_name.Text = val.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
             TexBo_add.Text  = val.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
         }
         else
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('value not found');", true);
     }
 }
```